# GEdit/Python execution plugin?

Tags: python, plugins, gedit

I'm just starting out learning python with GEdit plus various plugins as my IDE.

Visual Studio/F# has a feature  which permits the highlighting on a piece of text in the code window which then, on a keypress, gets executed in the F# console.

Is there a similar facility/plugin which would enable this sort of behaviour for GEdit/Python? I do have various execution type plugins (Run In Python,Better Python Console) but they don't give me this particular behaviour - or at least I'm not sure how to configure them to give me this. I find it useful because in learning python, I have some test code I want to execute particular individual lines or small segments of code (rather then a complete file) to try and understand what they are doing (and the copy/paste can get a bit tiresome)

... or perhaps there is a better way to do code exploration?

Many thx

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, and hopefully guide you in a direction you'll be happier with, I think you ought to consider trying some different editors.  There are many with more powerful code exploration features than GEdit has.  Check out this post:

[What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you use "external tools plugin"

- http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/ToolLauncherPlugin

As an example,

1. Edit > Preferences
2. Plugins
3. Tick "External Tools"
4. Close the Preferences Window
5. Tools > Manage External Tools
6. Click the "Add new too" icon in the bottom left
7. Name it "Execute Highlighted Python Code"
8. give it a keyboard shortcut
9. change the input combo box to : "highlighted selection"
10. change the output to : "Display in Bottom Pane"
11. In the editor window for the tool, replace everything with :

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
result = eval(sys.stdin.read())
print expression, "=>", result, type(result)
```

.

Comment: FWIW, in gedit 3.8.3 I get a syntax error even when copying the same syntax into ipython works fine.

Comment: Excellent idea. I, however, would use `exec` in line 2, and have the `print` statement in line 3 removed, since that would help in writing code in a more portable fashion

Comment: Doesn't work. Besides using the obsolete python2 syntax for printing, it also complains about `expression` variable not existing. [This answer works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946529/2388257).

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to see the result of entire `.py` file, you can put this code in your new created external tool window

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
exec(sys.stdin.read())
```

and change the `Input` **to** `Current document`.

Answer (score 3):

For python, You can use "external tools plugin":

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 "$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH"
```

Option of external tool:
Save: Current Document
Input: Current Document
Output: Display in bottom panel

Language: Python or Python3

Don't forget the quotes around $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH....

Comment: Yes, this is one simple solution. I did this too.

Comment: Works as of 2020. FTR, I had some problem with output not appearing, which turned out that some shortcuts were assigned but haven't been triggering the action. In fact, most of the shortcuts has this problem. To figure out which one works I had to leave a syntax error inside the plugin text field, and keep reassigning the keybinding till I saw gedit complains about a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I installed iPython console in gedit and do most of my simple scripting in it, but gedit is a very simple editor, so it'll not have some advance feature like an IDE

But if you want code exploring, or auto completion, I recommend a real IDE like Eclipse.

If you just want a editor, KomodoEdit is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is keep a file called python_temp.py.  I have a shortcut to it in my dock.  I use it as a scratch pad.  Whenever I want to quickly run some code, I copy the code, click the shortcut in the doc, paste in the text and hit f5 to run.  Quick, easy, simple, flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/BetterPythonConsole.

You hit F5 and it runs the code in your file in a IDLE-like console. I don't know if it can only run selected code. (I don't think it can) but you can always copy the needed code in a new window and run it from there.

Have a look through the plugin list for other interesting stuff: http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

Answer (score 1):

The closest to a decent IDE...
Install gedit-developer-plugins (through synaptic || apt-get) and don't forget to enable (what you need) from gEdit's plugins (Edit->Preferences [tab] plugins)  and happy coding