# How to run Python3.6 (Installed from pyenv) Code from Gedit

Tags: python, gedit, pyenv

I found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995041/gedit-python-execution-plugin) to run python code from gedit as an external tool with a shortcut,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import sys
exec(sys.stdin.read())
```

its working like charm. But i have a problem i am unable to run python3.6 using this script, i downloaded python3.6 using pyenv directory for python3.6 is

> /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4

when i tried to change directory in script it says permissions denied.